# Reason for having TempStatStore in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

Could any one give me the reason for what is the purpose of TempStatStores and derby.log fiels in hadoop and when these will be created.?

while trying to execute a query in hive, i'm getting an error: unable to create **TempStatStore**

Answer (score 1):

from http://osdir.com/ml/general/2011-05/msg06513.html

TempStatsStore is a derby database for stats gathering (intermediate stats). You can turn off stats gathering by set hive.stats.autogather=false